# dask read_parquet runs out of memory

Tags: dask

I'm trying to read a big (will not fit in memory) parquet dataset, amd then sample from it. Each partition of the dataset fits perfectly in memory.

The dataset is about 20Gb of data on disk, divided in 104 partitions of about 200Mb each. I don't want to use more than 40Gb of memory at any point, so i'm setting the `n_workers` and `memory_limit` accordingly.

My hypothesis was that Dask would load as many partitions as it could handle, sample from them, scrap them from memory and then continue loading the next ones. Or something like that.

Instead, judging by the execution graph (104 load operations in parallel, after each a sample), it looks like it tries to load all partitions simultaneously, and therefore the workers keep getting killed for running out of memory.

Am I missing something?

This is my code:

```py
from datetime import datetime

from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client(n_workers=4, memory_limit=10e9) #Gb per worker

import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_parquet('/path/to/dataset/')
df = df.sample(frac=0.01)

df = df.compute()
```

To reproduce the error you can create a mock dataset 1/10th the size of the one I was trying to load using this code, and try my code with 1GB `memory_limit=1e9` to compensate.

```py
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client() #add restrictions depending on your system here

from dask import datasets

df = datasets.timeseries(end='2002-12-31')
df = df.repartition(npartitions=104)
df.to_parquet('./mock_dataset')
```

Comment: Hi Eduardo, 
how much ram do you have in your machine? I tried to reproduce your problem with a machine with 16 GB and I assigned 4 workers with 3 GB of RAM each and your code worked just fine.

Comment: is that 200GB *on disc*?

Comment: @rpanai it's a server with RAM in the hundreds, but I'm not the only one using it. That's why I mentioned I assume I have 40Gb (I definitely have more, but it should be enough). How big was the dataset you loaded?

Comment: @mdurant yes, 200GB on disc. I'll edit the post to make that clearer.

Comment: Do you mind to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve)? I tried your code and it's working just fine for me.

Comment: @rpanai I added code to generate a mock dataset in the description

Comment: @Eduardo I create the mock dataset following your code and setting `memory_limit=5e8` I didn't receive any memory error. Do you mind to share your `dask.__version__` and `df.memory_usage(deep=True).sum()/1024**2` when reading the biggest partition from your real data with `pd.read_parquet`?

Comment: `dask.__version__ = 2.3.0`
`df.memory_usage(deep=True).sum()/1024**2 = 85.51`

Comment: My version is  `2.4.0` if it could help? Have you tried to reproduce the error with you `mock_dataset`?

Comment: @rpanai I tried updating dask and pyarrow, but no luck. Yes I get the error with the mock_dataset. Have you made any modifications to your `~/.config/dask/distributed.yaml` file? I'm using the default values.

Comment: No I didn't make any change

Answer (score 2):

Parquet is an efficient binary format, with encoding and compression. There is a very good chance that in memory, it takes up far more space than you think.

In order to sample the data at 1%, each partition is being loaded and expanded into memory in entirety, before being sub-selected. This comes with considerable memory overhead of buffer copies. Each worker thread will need to accommodate the currently-processed chunk, as well as results that have been accumulated so far on that worker, and then a task will copy all of these for the final concat operation (which also involves copies and overhead).

The general recommendation is that each worker should have access to "several times" the in-memory size of each partition, and in your case, those are ~2GB on-disc and bigger in memory.

Comment: Sorry the 200Gb was a typo, the actual number is 20Gb. The partition size was right though, it's 200Mb, and the worker has 10Gb limit, it should not be a problem. Further more, if I set one worker with 10Gb and load just one partition (not the entire dataset) it can load it fine, so each partition must fit in memory.

Comment: So I suggest you measure the effect of loading, sampling and storing the memory in data, numbers here will be key.